# di/dt for R of general RLC, KCL dt algebra

Tags: passive-networks

Basic question. This is an exercise which requires all initial values for i and v0 (both 0), final values (yielding 2,4 A and 9,6 V)

[image]

It also asks for di/dt and my question lies on the answer given (last equation, giving di/dt = 4A/s)

I tried writing a KCL equation to observe the currents better, but how do I keep the current source value after deriving the equation

How does it imply that ic = 4

Comment: Ic = 4 amps right at t = 0+. The final steady state voltage is 9.6 volts just by inspection. And the final steady state current through R1 is 2.4 amps. Are these what you are trying to evaluate?

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At t = 0+ the dominant component is the capacitor C1. Its effect trumps any effects from R1 and super-trumps any effect from L1 in series with R2. So, at t = 0+ C1 acts like a short circuit and starts to charge up taking all the 4 amps from the current source. Given this: -

$$i_c = C\cdot \frac{dv}{dt}$$

We can say that the initial rate of change of voltage is \$\frac{4}{0.25}\$ volts per second (16 volts per second) hence, the initial rate of change of current through R1 is 4 amps per second.

After everything has settled down and in the fullness of time C1 acts like an open circuit and L1 acts like a short circuit hence all the current from the current source (4 amps) feeds R1 || R2 and produces a terminal voltage of 4 amps x 2.4 ohms = 9.6 volts.

This implies a current through R1 of 2.4 amps and a current through R2 of 1.6 amps.

Comment: the fact that the capacitor is short circuit at t=0 was not clear to me. Does the inductor act like an open circuit at t=0 aswell? Thanks anyway

Comment: Yes it does @Atlas